# Does D have futures / promises?

Tags: d

I want to implement my own task system based on [Naughy Dogs fiber based task system](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1022186/Parallelizing-the-Naughty-Dog-Engine).

I want to do it roughly like this

```d
auto fiber = new Fiber((){
    someFunction();
});
```

Then I want to give that fiber to a thread that I have created. That shouldn't be a problem.

But sometimes I want to get a result back, maybe `someFunction`is of type `int function()`.

```d
auto t = task!someFunction();
auto fiber = new Fiber((){
    task.yieldForce;
});
submitFiberToSomeThreadPool(fiber);
```

But it seems that I can not use a `Task` like that. It seems I have to submit it into a Taskpool or I have to call `executeInNewThread` which I don't want.

Does this mean I would have to implement my own future promise system?

Comment: so you want to pass values around between fiber and caller/pass them as argument in the yield function?

Comment: I checked the presentation and the title "Parallelizing the Naughty Dog Engine Using Fibers" caught my eye. - How can someone put terms "parallel" and "fiber" together??

Comment: There isn't anything inherently contradicting between fibers and parallelism. There isn't inherently common either :) Using N fibers + M threads is better for parallelism than using N threads, that is something I'd expect without reading the presentation.

Comment: Right term is concurrency, not parallelism. If you have 1 core to run your app, you can't have parallelism! On the other hand, you can have threads, and fibers!

Answer (score 2):

`Fiber` is a very basic primitive. There is a more higher level task system implemented in vibe.d - specifically, you question seems to fit for http://vibed.org/api/vibe.core.concurrency/async

```d
import vibe.core.core;
import vibe.core.concurrency;

void main ( )
{
    // "root" task, necessary as one can't suspend main
    // thread as it isn't wrapped by fiber
    runTask({
        auto future = async({
            sleep(500.msecs);
            return 42;
        });

        sleep(250.msecs);
        int value = future.getResult();

        exitEventLoop();
    });

    runEventLoop();
}
```